# Configuring HTTP endpoint with SOAP in Mule Flows

Tags: soap, cxf, mule

I am trying to configure an existing SOAP web service in Mule using Mule Flows. I have an HTTP endpoint with request/response and a SOAP component, say Service A.

[image: Simple SOAP flow]
I want to configure this setup for a simple flow to work. I have set my HTTP endpoint and the SOAP service. The flow file is shown below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="CE-3.2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd ">
    <flow name="demoflowFlow1" doc:name="demoflowFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <cxf:jaxws-service port="8082" serviceClass="com.myapp.serviceA.ServiceAImplService" doc:name="SOAP"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

This is not working. My service is a simple one and it takes in a string and returns a string.

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://service.demo.myapp.com/", endpointInterface = "com.myapp.demo.service.IServiceA", portName = "ServiceAImplPort", serviceName = "ServiceAImplService")
public class ServiceAImpl implements IServiceA {
    public String hello(String user) {
        return "at service A: " + user;
    }
}
```

I am invoking my flow with the HTTP inbound URL http://localhost:8081/{I am not sure what goes here!} and getting:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>No such operation: (HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /)</faultstring>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The Mule flow is running as an application in Mule Studio, and the service is running as a SOAP web service from Springsource toolsuite.

What am I doing wrong?

Original WSDL at http://localhost:8080/ServiceA/services/ServiceAImplPort?wsdl

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://service.demo.myapp.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="ServiceAImplService" targetNamespace="http://service.demo.myapp.com/">
<wsdl:types>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://service.demo.myapp.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<import namespace="http://service.demo.myapp.com/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/ServiceA/services/ServiceAImplPort?xsd=serviceaimpl_schema1.xsd"/>
</schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="helloResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:helloResponse" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="hello">
<wsdl:part element="tns:hello" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IServiceA">
<wsdl:operation name="hello">
<wsdl:input message="tns:hello" name="hello"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:helloResponse" name="helloResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="ServiceAImplServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:IServiceA">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="hello">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:Hello" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="hello">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="helloResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="ServiceAImplService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:ServiceAImplServiceSoapBinding" name="ServiceAImplPort">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ServiceA/services/ServiceAImplPort"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

FYI, I can run the web service from SpringSource toolsuite without issues. Now, how do I invoke the web service from my HTTP inbound URL with a GET request?
[I presume simple web services like these take GET requests.]

Comment: SOAP web services are accessed with POST not GET. In your case, have you considered using a simple-service pattern instead of a flow? http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Simple+Service+Pattern

Comment: Actually, I am not too clear about consuming a SOAP web-service in a flow. Once I get this pat, I will move to a much more complex flow where there are parallel calls to multiple services and I will have to use choice routers while invoking some services too. So, I will have to use the flow pattern anyway.

Comment: You're correct: the flow pattern is what you need.

Comment: Have you managed to get it working? I am in a similar dilemma now.

Comment: Yes, I managed to get it working. AMA and I can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot the @WebMethod annotation at your method. This is basically what your error says: No operation.

[Here](http://www.learnbysimpleway.com/2012/10/mule-3-esb-cxf-soap-webservice-ws.html) is a very good example how you can do it.

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://service.demo.myapp.com/", endpointInterface = "com.myapp.demo.service.IServiceA", portName = "ServiceAImplPort", serviceName = "ServiceAImplService")
public class ServiceAImpl implements IServiceA {
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name="result")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name="user")String user) {
        return "at service A: " + user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your link is dead now:(

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy ... I guess com.myapp.serviceA.ServiceAImplService is your Service Implementation class and IServiceA.java is your Service class ...  why don't you try this :-

[image: Mule Config]

There is something wrong in your wsdl.... Why **< wsdl:service name="ServiceAImplService" >** is **ServiceAImplService** ... instead it should be **IServiceA** .... **ServiceAImplService** is the web service implementation class I guess and should be kept in  in mule flow